# Error with matching account and contact in custom object (flow)

Tags: workflow, process-builder, lightning-connect, visual-flows

Error with matching account and contact in custom object (flow)
Greetings, I am creating a custom product donation object which includes lookups for both contact and account. The account being corporate/school/business etc in some instances and the contact being the individual. As we are a nonprofit, we currently use the 1 to 1 model with person accounts, namely individuals who would both be a contact and account as they are not tied, though they could be tied to households. In the instance that we are receiving a product donation from an individual donor who is not related to a business, we are looking to determine a way to tie the contact into its corresponding account record.

Here's what it will look like.

[image]

I am attempting to build a workflow within the Lightning process builder which enables me then to assess is the Account Field is null and then tied the contact record to its corresponding account as when an individual record is created it is then tied to its account. We are using a grid system to batch create donations manually, in the event that a new contact needs to be manually created.

As such we get this message.

The flow failed to access the value for myVariable_current.Account__r.Name because it hasn't been set or assigned

Is there anything I should do to address.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 2):

I think I understand what you are attempting to do here...

It seems that you are using some version of the "Account.Name" instead of "Account.Id"?  That seems to be the issue based on your error message, and not something else.  Your Process Builder should look similar to this image:

[image]

Comment: Perfect. This works, many thanks. The records create and seem to be populating just fine.

Comment: Also another questions, in the event that a contact and account name are different, we would like to be able to tie the contact to the account, is there a workflow strategy that we can utilize?

Comment: You would possibly want to check a box after this update happens (so add a record update, after you create a boolean).  Once this box is checked and your Account <> NULL, then fire off the Process Builder and do this exact opposite flow, grab the Account.Id from the Donation, and then go ahead and update the Contact.Id.   Just switching it around.  The Checkbox is so (i assume) you dont want it firing on every donation record you have... if you do, then ignore that.